# Autocomplete textbox don't show result inside clicking of textbox

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I have a `autocomplete` `textbox` which filters exactly what I want to search for. But now what I want is,

> If user doesn't types anything into the `textbox` and just clicks the `textbox`. It should show all the result. Is this possbile ?

Below is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $("#txt712").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Frm_Agreement_Master.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                    data: "{'username':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            },
            focus: function () {
                return false;
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var terms = split(this.value);
                terms.pop();
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                terms.push("");
                this.value = terms.join(", ");
                return false;
            }
        });
        $("#txt712").bind("keydown", function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }
        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }
    }
```

Also find the link from where I got the reference.

[Reference link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/07/jquery-autocomplete-textbox-with.html)

**UPDATE**

Server side code

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (OracleConnection ObjPriCon = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString()))
    {
        using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select distinct survey_area_7_12 FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst WHERE survey_area_7_12 LIKE '%' || :searchtext || '%'", ObjPriCon))
        {
            ObjPriCon.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":searchtext", username.ToLower());
            OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["survey_area_7_12"].ToString());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this can be done at server end. I checked the reference link, and the 'C# executing sql query' . by validating if the search string in empty you have modify the query to fetch all the results (select *, instead of select distinct) and send all the results to frontend and populate

Comment: @Mehavel: Ok, can you help me with some code? I cant imagine what exactly has to be done.

Comment: @Div: Yes, it make sense and it will help me more if I get some code to imagine here

Answer (score 1):

In Server code check if the search string is null or not and trigger the query accorduingly

```
    public static List<string> GetAutoCompleteData(string username)
    {
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SureshDasari;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=MySampleDB"))
    {

     **//check if user name is not null**
    if(null != username){
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT UserName from UserInformation where UserName LIKE '%'+@SearchText+'%'", con))}
    else{
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select UserName from UserInformation, con))}
}
    {
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SearchText", username);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
    result.Add(dr["UserName"].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: I didn't understand ur code. Should I use it and check ?

Comment: hmm. when you search string ('username') is empty, just change the query to 'select username from user table' to return all the results. if the column you are searching is not nullable, there will not be any results for ''(empty) search string

Comment: I guess it wont work, unless there is some event called inside click of textbox. Coz, When I click no event fires with your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Focus" event to do this.

```
.focus(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```

Full code as below.

```
    $("#txt712").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Frm_Agreement_Master.aspx/GetAutoCompleteData",
                data: "{'username':'" + extractLast(request.term) + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        },
        focus: function () {
            $(this).autocomplete("search"); //New Code
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var terms = split(this.value);
            terms.pop();
            terms.push(ui.item.value);
            terms.push("");
            this.value = terms.join(", ");
            return false;
        }
    });
```